# \hphantom behaving like \mbox, not like the counterpart of \vphantom

Tags: spacing, boxes

I have the following figure as part of a slideshow I'm writing with `beamer`. If it is relevant, I've used `pst-jtree` (which is essentially a bunch of macros over `pstricks`) to produce the tree branches.

[image]

The code that produces the right-hand node is:

`{multiline Sluicing Elicitation \cr $\underbracket{\textrm{Protocol}}_{typology}$ \endmultiline}`

Note how the underbracket *typology* only goes the width of *Protocol*, which is visually unpleasant. Ideally, I'd like it to be width of the upper line *Sluicing Elicitation*. The following figure is what I'm aiming at (I've produced this figure by adding an `mbox` to either side of `textrm{Protocol}` in the line above and then manually adjusting the width of both `mbox`es until it looked good; clearly a very inefficient method).

[image]

I've tried to do this with `hphantom{}`, which should be the horizontal counterpart of `vphantom{}` ---i.e., it produces a box of zero height and the width of  whatever is inside the brackets, and doesn't disturb the actual text. But if I write this

`{multiline Sluicing Elicitation \cr $\underbracket{\hphantom{Sluicing Elicitation}\textrm{Protocol}}_{typology}$ \endmultiline}`

I get this

[image]

which is effectively the equivalent of adding an `mbox` with the width of *Sluicing Elicitation*. The question I have is: am I using `hphantom{}` in the wrong way? And if not (i.e., if it is producing the result it is meant to produce), how can I get the result I want?

*Because I've been in SE long enough to know that someone will say this:* I guess I can get the result I want by putting the multiline text in a `minipage` and then underbracketing the minipage itself, or whatever. I'm asking this question despite knowing that this type of solutions exist because I don't just want to get this particular result; I also want to understand why I'm not getting there with `hphantom`.

Comment: With package `calc` you can do `\makebox[\widthof{Ellipsis Consortium}]{Protocol}`

Comment: `\hphantom{#1}` does exactly what it should: adds as much horizontal space as is the width of `#1`.

Comment: You are in horizontal mode so the `\hphantom` and the following text are side by side. You get something similar with `\vphantom` if you are in vertical mode.

Comment: what you want to do is *overlay* "Protocol" centered on the width of the phantom box, not add the two widths.  so @egreg`s suggestion is the best approach.  and if you want the two underbrackets at the same depth, you should add a `\strut` after "Protocol", since it doesn't have a descender, whereas "Ellipsis" does.

Answer (score 3):

Add `\usepackage{calc}` to your document preamble and use

```
\makebox[\widthof{Ellipsis Consortium}]{Protocol}
```

when you want the phantom. This makes a box as wide as “Ellipsis Consortium”, with “Protocol” centered in the available space.